# Creating Trigger is giving me Error

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have created a `Trigger` to insert values in table. But while compiling it, I am getting error as

> Error(10,80): PL/SQL: ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name

Below is my trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_UPDATE_FR_LOGTYPE1 
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON LOGSAPDEALSLIPFUNDREQINTGRTN 
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

       IF (:NEW.RESPONSESTRING LIKE '%Record already exists%'
           AND:NEW.LOGTYPE = 'ServiceFault')
       THEN
          --:NEW.LOGTYPE := 'Success';
          Insert into LOGSAPDEALSLIPFUNDREQINTGRTN (LOGTYPE) values (:NEW.LOGTYPE := 'Success');      
       END IF;    
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to edit this way:

```
...
Insert into LOGSAPDEALSLIPFUNDREQINTGRTN (LOGTYPE) values ('Success');
...
```

Comment: I added as per your answer, but it is not updating the column with Success message.

Comment: You posted a question about a syntax issue, and this solves it. If you have an issue with the logic of your trigger, please edit the question by clarifying what the trigger should do.